# How to define a name for an exception in python?

Tags: python-3.x, try-except

I`m trying to handle the exception 'ProfileNotExistsException' and the code is as follows:

```
    try:
        profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(bot.context, followees[i])
        #Other statements
    except ProfileNotExistsException:
        print('exception')
```

But This NameError is occurring.

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [11], in <cell line: 2>()
      6     allfolloweesDataList.append((profile.userid,profile.username,profile.full_name,profile.followers,profile.followees,profile.is_verified,profile.biography,profile.external_url))
      7     print(i,end=',')
----> 8 except ProfileNotExistsException:
      9     print('exception')

NameError: name 'ProfileNotExistsException' is not defined
```

How can I define a name for an exception like this?

Comment: `except ProfileNotExistsException as e:` and then use the variable name `e` inside the except block. But if you're trying to catch a `ProfileNotExistsException`, then you need to actually import the `ProfileNotExistsException` class from wherever it's defined (should be `from instaloader import ProfileNotExistsException` I think), or catch a more generic exception type.

Comment: Thanks but can you explain what`s the logic behind it.

Comment: Do you define this `ProfileNotExistsException` before?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy they aren't asking about `except Whatever as e`, they just mean how do you use `Whatever`.

Comment: @I'mahdi no, I just tried to handle it like other common exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/instaloader/instaloader) for the `instaloader` package, I believe this is what you are looking for:

```py
from instaloader.exceptions import ProfileNotExistsException

try:
    profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(bot.context, followees[i])
    ...
except ProfileNotExistsException:
    print('exception')
```

- [`instaloader.exceptions`](https://github.com/instaloader/instaloader/blob/master/instaloader/exceptions.py)
- [`instaloader.exceptions.ProfileNotExistsException`](https://github.com/instaloader/instaloader/blob/4bb32e3c5a709f1e200470a63a9e2974b5a43b7f/instaloader/exceptions.py#L16)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough. There are three options.

## I. You don't have such an existing class

```py
class ProfileNotExistsException(ValueError):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return 'Profile doesn\'t exist!'
```

You need to create such a class, and based on its name, it should extend `ValueError`. Then you can catch it.

## II. There is such a class

Just import it, or in your case it might be `instaloader.ProfileNotExistsException`

## III. You actually don't want to catch *only this* exception

Use

```py
try:
    pass #...
except BaseException: # ValueError IndexError...
    pass #...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the contributors. The real problem was that the exception 'ProfileNotExistsException' was not defined in the code. We can handle the common exceptions easily as they are already defined check the list of [a built-in exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#bltin-exceptions).

So, If the exception is not the one from the built-in exceptions, we have to define this exception in our code before calling it. Thanks